# Distinct pivot results with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, eloquent

Inside my Laravel project, I'm printing out all the business cards of my contacts.

In the contact model I have:

```
    public function organizations()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('Organization')->withPivot('ContractStatus')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

So in that way, I can show all the companies the contact is still working for.

In the footer of my contacts overview page, I want to print out all the associated companies logo's for that particular search query.

But something like this:

```
@foreach($contacts as $key => $value)
    @foreach($value->organizations as $organization)

    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Will print duplicated company logo's as soon as the search results contains 2 contacts that both work for the same company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to list a distinct collection of a collection of contacts, then don't use relation, but `whereHas`:

```
$contactsIds = $contacts->modelKeys();

$organizations = Organization::whereHas('contacts', function ($q) use ($contactsIds) {
  $q->whereIn('contacts.id', $contactsIds);
})->get();
```

---

Another way would be this trick, in case you in fact need to load the relation:

```
$organizations = null;

$contacts = Contact::with(['organizations' => function ($q) use (&$organizations) {
  $organizations = $q->get();
}])->get();

$organizations = $organizations->unique();
```

This will load the relation as usually and also run additional query and assign its result to `$organizations`.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller action generate a new Collection with the organizations:

```
$uniqueOrganizations = new Collection();
foreach($contacts as $contact)
    $uniqueOrganizations->merge($contact->organizations);
```

Then pass it to the view, to show all the different organizations

```
@foreach($uniqueOrganizations as $org)
      //show org logo
@endforeach
```